Наречие от прилагательного "выдающийся"?
Подскажите пожалуйста, как от прилагательного "выдающийся" образовать наречие? Нужно охарактеризовать некоторое действие или достижение как выдающееся и желательно одним словом.
Есть такое слово "выдающе"?

Исключительно, достойно, неповторимо. И фраза нужна.

Еще; на редкость, единственно, блистательно, блестяще, феноменально. Технология придумывания простая: к слову выдающийся находите синонимы, а от них образуете наречия. https://text.ru/synonym/выдающийся  Наиболее грамотно, конечно, подбор по тексту.

Выдающееся (не рядовое) всегда штучно, т.е. уникально.

Из ответов справочной службы Грамоты.ру:

Вопрос № 310375
Потрясающий - потрясающе, впечатляющий - впечатляюще, выдающийся - ?
Если такого наречия официально нет, то просьба наиболее грамотно его придумать! Спасибо!
ОТВЕТ
Грамотно придумать невозможно. Мешает постфикс -ся.

